# How to set shipping charges in Paypal SOAP API express checkout

Tags: c#-4.0, paypal, express-checkout, paypal-soap

I am adding an item of 20.00 and setting the order total to 22.00

```
 paymentDetails.OrderTotal = new PayPalSandboxWS.BasicAmountType()
     {
         currencyID = ConvertProgramCurrencyToPayPalSandbox(currency),
         Value = "22.00"
     };
```

and setting the shipping total to 2.00

```
 paymentDetails.ShippingTotal = new PayPalSandboxWS.BasicAmountType()
     {
         currencyID = ConvertProgramCurrencyToPayPalSandbox(currency),
         Value = "2.00"
     };
```

But I am getting this error: `The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.`

Please assist

Comment: I have exactly the same and was wondering if you have found a solution? Can't find anything in the docs about it: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_SetExpressCheckout

Comment: Do you also have: SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType sdt = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();
        sdt.ShippingMethod = ShippingServiceCodeType.CustomCode;
        sdt.ShippingMethodSpecified = true;

Answer (score 1):

You missed setting the `ItemTotal` value! That caused this erorr:

```
double itemTot  = 20.0;
double tot      = 22.0;
double shipping = 2.0;
string desc     = "";
var paymentDetailsItemTypes = new List<PaymentDetailsItemType>();

PaymentDetailsType pdt = new PaymentDetailsType()
{        
    OrderDescription = desc,
    OrderTotal = new BasicAmountType()
    {
        currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.EUR,
        Value = tot.ToString("0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    },
    PaymentDetailsItem = paymentDetailsItemTypes.ToArray(),
    ShippingTotal = new BasicAmountType()
    {
        currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.EUR,
        Value = shipping.ToString("0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    },
    ItemTotal = new BasicAmountType()
    {
        currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.EUR,
        Value = itemTot.ToString("0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    }
};
```